# php ini value '-1' what does it mean?

Tags: php

I want to allow persistent connections in php.ini

So I changed `mysqli___allow_persistent` to on:

but I have this value too:

```
mysqli___max_persistent: -1
```

what does -1 mean?

Comment: The -1 does not make any sense - see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php

Comment: Did you manually set it to -1? A value of 0 means unlimited persistent connections according to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php).

Comment: no, it was already set in my php.ini @PatNeedham

Comment: @EdHeal strange... it was already set in my php.ini. thank you, friend!